# Flutter IOS live and testflight build freeze on launch screen

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight, live

I am getting issues in live and test flight build only, in debug mode not getting this issue.

when I checked the logs I found this

fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...

Anyone here who are facing same issue or who have any solution please revert, Much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm seeing this too, with a flutter module (add to app)

Comment: @LazyDave can you please elaborate?